# Framework Options to consume Rest Services From .Net

Tags: .net, rest, restful-architecture

I am undertaking some research into Rest Services in .Net and I trying to discover whether Microsoft .Net provides a number of different frameworks for consuming Rest Services and whether each framework has its own pros and cons in the same way Java does. Further, I would like to know whether there is any advantages of using .Net Framework 4.5 over Framework 4.

Has anyone had any experiences of this and could provide some guidance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.Net Framework 4.5 allows asynchronous operations.

Comment: Can you expand your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure wheather .net framework has a lot of REST APIs, but you can build your own using WCF REST. And .net 4.5 has support for asynchrous  operations,that was not there in .net 4.0

Comment: Thanks, but are there any third party alternative frameworks that i can look at?

Comment: I'll let you know when I get to know about one.